# Compiling Tesseract OCR on 64 bit Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, tesseract

I'm trying to compile Tesseract OCR into a Windows 64 bit version of the library. I've downloaded the source and got it compiling to a 32 bit version using Visual Studio Express C++ 2010, but as I'm not usually a C++ programmer, I'm at a loss as to how I move over to compiling a 64 bit version.

Any help would be really appreciated.

The reason I need a 64 bit version is that I'm using it as part of a Java project that requires a 64-bit JVM. The 32 bit version of Tesseract clearly won't work in the 64 bit JVM, but there doesn't seem to be an official 64 bit Windows build.

Comment: You need to switch the platform in Visual Studio, right click on solution, properties, Configuration Properties on the left and then click on the drop-down "Platform" and pick something 64-bit. If it's not there, most likely the project wasn't prepared for 64-bit compilation, but you can still try building it with a 64-bit target by adding a new platform target and basing it on x86 one.

Comment: Thanks Bartek - there's no other Platform there, only Win32. How do I add a new platform target?

Comment: Click `Configuration Manager`, `Active Solution Platform`, `New...` and "copy settings from" Win32.

Comment: I'm guessing there should be something 64-bit-esque in the 'Type or select the new platform' box for me to select? Mine's blank...

Comment: Aha-em-ish-yes. Mine shows Win32, x64, Itanium and ARM. Do you have 64-bit compiler installed?

Comment: I suspect not. I've spent the afternoon trying to install the Windows 7 SDK so I had one (I had a feeling I'd need something!), and failing. I might need to invest some time in setting up a Virtual Machine with a clean install of Windows on so I can get the SDK properly installed and give it a go in that.

Comment: Well it is rather hard to create 64-bit binaries without 64-bit compiler :). Anyway, when you have it, redo all the steps above. If you're lucky, it might just work. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant 64-bit DLLs are provided by [Tesseract .NET wrapper](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/tree/master/src/lib/TesseractOcr/x64) project. You may want to check out its solution/project configuration to see how the DLLs are compiled.